# How to keep my accelerometer awake with screen off with Sony SmartwatchMN2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I want to know the method of keeping my accelerometer awake with screen off. 
In the developer documentation(SmartWatch_WP_1.pdf in Smart Extension SDK), I read that

- the sensor is stopped when the control is paused
- the control is not paused by using ControlExtention#setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_OFF).
- the control is paused by the user operation or time elapses.

So I tried to use ControlExtention#setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_OFF).
After one minute, the control was paused and the accelerometer was stopped.
But it was not paused when the power cable connected.
Of course I want to keeping the accelerometer awake when power cable not connected.

I also tried the wakelock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK) and Service#startForeground, but i didn't get well.

Are there ways to resolve this problem?

My Configuration is

- Device

  - Sony Smartwatch MN2
- Smartwatch Version

  - 0.1.A.3.7
- Host Application Version

  - 1.2.37

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We are looking into this - I will get back to this thread if and when I know more.

**Update**

An update of the SmartWatch application was published on Google Play on March 14th (2013). This update includes a fix for the above Sensor problem.