# How to keep light sensor awake when screen is off for Sony Smartwatch 2?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Sony: Any update on this?

I am trying to write a Control Extension that will read light sensor data from the Sony Smartwatch 2 in the background, even while the watch's screen backlight goes off and the screen shows the clock time.

The problem is that as soon as the backlight turns off and the clock appears, the sensorEvent.getSensorValues() will only return zero for the light sensor. Waking the screen up again will cause getSensorValues() to start returning non-zero values again.

A similar question was asked over a year ago (for the accelerometer), and I have confirmed that the accelerometer continues to return valid values when the screen is locked.

**However, as soon as the screen locks, the light sensor only returns zero.**

Maybe the accelerometer issue was fixed last year for the MN2, but the problem still occurs for the light sensor on the SW2?

[How to keep my accelerometer awake with screen off with Sony SmartwatchMN2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602556/how-to-keep-my-accelerometer-awake-with-screen-off-with-sony-smartwatchmn2)

Comment: You are probably facing the same situation as with the accelerometer senser (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22377167/1373568). In short, there is an interrupt mechanism (for battery purpose I guess) which stops all sensors when there is no control extension or when the control extension is paused.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking into supporting use cases such as this.  Please check developer.sonymobile.com for updates.

Comment: Marlin, thanks much. I will keep an eye out and am eagerly awaiting an update.

Comment: Marlin, I tested this again with the latest SW2 update tonight. It seems the problem is not solved. The accelerometer keeps sending data after the screen locks and the backlight turns off, but the light sensor stops when the  backlight turns off. Do you know if the developers addressed this issue in the latest update?

Comment: There were no changes to this in the latest update.  At this time no estimate on when/if changes will be made unfortunately.